# Jenkins Xcode builds use old changes

Tags: xcode, mercurial, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins to pull from a mercurial repository and then build with Xcode. The problem is the ipa file being generated does not include the latest changes from the repro. It looks like it's missing recently added assets from the repo. The most perplexing part is if I actually run the project in the simulator using the local repro everything is fine. If it helps I have the "Clean" option enabled in Jenkins for both mercurial and Xcode.